# Validation error: Error: Element img is missing required attribute src Error: An img element must have an alt attribute

Tags: html

I could use some help with this as it will not validate.

Validation error:

> Error: Element img is missing required attribute src.
>
> Error: An img element must have an alt attribute, except under certain conditions ?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
        <title>My picture modal</title>

        <style>
        #myImg {
            border-radius: 5px;
            cursor: pointer;
            transition: 0.3s;
        }

        #myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

        /* The Modal (background) */
        .modal {
            display: none; /* Hidden by default */
            position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
            z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
            padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%; /* Full width */
            height: 100%; /* Full height */
            overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
            background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
        }

        /* Modal Content (image) */
        .modal-content {
            margin: auto;
            display: block;
            width: 80%;
            max-width: 700px;
        }

        /* Caption of Modal Image */
        #caption {
            margin: auto;
            display: block;
            width: 80%;
            max-width: 700px;
            text-align: center;
            color: #ccc;
            padding: 10px 0;
            height: 150px;
        }

        /* Add Animation */
        .modal-content, #caption {
            -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
            animation-name: zoom;
            animation-duration: 0.6s;
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes zoom {
            from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)}
            to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
        }

        @keyframes zoom {
            from {transform:scale(0)}
            to {transform:scale(1)}
        }

        /* The Close Button */
        .close {
            position: absolute;
            top: 15px;
            right: 35px;
            color: #f1f1f1;
            font-size: 40px;
            font-weight: bold;
            transition: 0.3s;
        }

        .close:hover,
        .close:focus {
            color: #bbb;
            text-decoration: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        /* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
        @media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
            .modal-content {
                width: 100%;
            }
        }
        </style>
        </head>
        <body>

        <h2>Image Modal</h2>
        <p>In this example, we use CSS to create a modal (dialog box) that is hidden by default.</p>
        <p>We use JavaScript to trigger the modal and to display the current image inside the modal when it is clicked on. Also note that we use the value from the image's "alt" attribute as an image caption text inside the modal.</p>

        <img id="myImg" src="images/extraPix/TequilaSunrise.jpg" alt="My Tequila Sunrise" width="300" height="200">

        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div id="myModal" class="modal">
          <span class="close">×</span>

          <!--Validation error:    Error: Element img is missing required attribute src 
          Error: An img element must have an alt attribute, except under certain conditions ?Cannot find documentation for this.-->

          <img class="modal-content" id="img01">


          <div id="caption"></div>
        </div>
        <!--Get the modal-->
        <script>
        var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

        // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
        var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
        var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
        var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
        img.onclick = function(){
            modal.style.display = "block";
            modalImg.src = this.src;
            modalImg.alt = this.alt;
            captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
        }

        // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
        var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

        // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
        span.onclick = function() {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
        </script>

            enter code here

        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Well because your img doesnt have src and alt. I see you are getting those values with JS, but we need to see output of your code. Inspect the element or view source to see if that script is actually loading anything in your #img01.

Comment: Hello Shah and thank you for replying.

Comment: The error is a HTML error not js I believe. It renders fine it just won't validate

Comment: <img class="modal-content" id="img01" src="images/pixel.gif" alt="pixel gif"> Now it will validate.